# Expresión regular para Java FX , número de 0 - 5 con decimales incluidos

Tags: java, regex, javafx

Buenas tardes estoy realizando una pequeña aplicación en Java Fx y necesito validar uno de los campos , de manera que :

- Se admita solo un número del 0 a 5  [0-5] y que puedan incluir decimales (4.55,2.25  ...).

¿Sería lo más efectivo realizar una expresión regular? o ¿ Debería validarlo de alguna otra manera?.

En tal caso , ¿como sería la expresión ? con : ^(\d|-)?(\d|,)*.?\d*$
me aseguro de que solo se inserten números incluidos decimales, pero como podría modificarla para el rango 0-5? , un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este método te agregar una validación a la entrada en el TextField, evitando que se introduzcan valores no deseados. Si te das cuenta, se utiliza una expresión regular que permita introducir solo números decimales con punto y adicionalmente se utiliza un valor máximo para evitar que la entrada sea mayor a lo que se desea. Siempre puede modificar el código para que se ajuste mejor a tus necesidades. Este código también valida entradas a través de Ctrl + V.

```
public void addValidator() {
    final String pattern = "^(\\d)+(\\.?\\d*)?$";
    final int maxValue = 5;

    textField.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.V) {// Esto es para impedir el Ctrl + V de texto en los campos numéricos
            String textToPaste = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getString();

            if (textToPaste != null && !textToPaste.isEmpty()) {
                String newText = textField.getText() + textToPaste;

                if (!newText.matches(pattern) || Double.parseDouble(newText) > maxValue) {
                    event.consume();
                }
            } else {
                event.consume();
            }
        }
    });

    textField.setOnKeyTyped(event -> {
        String newText = textField.getText() + event.getCharacter();
        if (!newText.matches(pattern) || Double.parseDouble(newText) > maxValue) {
            event.consume();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Las expresiones saben lo que son digitos numéricos pero no tienen idea de que valor representa cada uno. no obstante, se puede escribir un patrón que simule la funcionalidad de un rango de valores, pero en ocaciones puede resultar más complicado que hacer una simple comparación.
Es más facil usar:

```
float f = 5.01f;
    if(f>=0 && f<=5){
        System.out.println("El valor("+f+") esta dentro del Rango");
    }else{
        System.out.println("El valor("+f+") esta Fuera del Rango");
    }
```

Pero de igual manera te puede servir esta expresión que valida un flotante de hasta 2 decimales(valores validos 0,0.01,3.0,4.9,4.99,5:

```
[0-4]{1}[.]+[0-9]{2}|[0-5]
```

Comment: Este regex puede coincidir con `no es 123.......456 un número`.